# How can i make this console query into laravel function query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, sum

[user checks relation]
[1][checks table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtLLP.png)
[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGTZ.png)got this console query to get the result i want but can't figure out how to make it a function in laravel.

```
select DATE(c.check_in),
       group_concat(users.id),
       sec_to_time(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(c.check_hours))) AS total_time
from users
         join checks c on users.id = c.user_id
where c.check_hours is not null
  and DATE(c.check_in) = '2022-11-17'
group by DATE(c.check_in)
```

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
        $today = Carbon::yesterday();
        $asdf = User::query()
            ->byNotWhereAdmin()
            ->with(['checks' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('check_hours', '08:00')
                    ->where('check_hours', '!=', null)
                    ->selectRaw('sum(TIME_TO_SEC(`check_hours`)) as total_time')
                    ->whereDate('check_in', '2022-11-17');
            }])
            ->get();
```

i did smth like this but cant figure out how to make the selectRaw() method to make a sum of times

```
sec_to_time(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(c.check_hours))) AS total_time
```

the result should be like this:

```
DATE(c.check_in) group_concat(users.id)         total_time
2022-11-17,      "2,8,11,5,15,16,4,6,14,7,13",  88:00:00
```

[console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MiVz.png)

I got a solution by changing the query from Users to Checks smth liek this:

```
 Check::query()
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(check_in, "%d-%b-%Y") as datetime'))
        ->selectRaw('sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(`check_hours`))) as total_time')
        ->with('user')
        ->where('check_hours', '!=', null)
        ->when($this->selectDate && $this->selectDate2, function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('check_in', [$this->selectDate, Carbon::parse($this->selectDate2)->addDays(1)]);
        }, function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('check_in', [$this->selectDate, $this->selectDate2]);
        })
        ->groupBy('check_in', 'check_hours')
        ->get();
```

and i did whereBetween to make a range date to search

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow juxhin! it would be best if you could spare time to check out [ask] and learn to write [mcve]. there are a lot of stuff going, and some are not quite clear - like what `->byNotWhereAdmin()` meant, why `sec_to_time` is not in `selectRaw`, did you get an error message? also, `with` does not imply an sql `join`. they behave differently.

Comment: sorry im new to stackoverflowm, and i might forget some explainning, 
->byNotWhereAdmin() is a function i have in my user model to exlude the user type of admin. and sec_to_time im not sure why is not in selectRaw i dont have the right idea where to put it. thank you for your time appriciated

Comment: @Bagus Tesa Thank you for your time and effort really appriciated! i couldn't find way to message you so im adding ti here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution by changing the query from Users to Checks something like below:

```php
Check::query()
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(check_in, "%d-%b-%Y") as datetime'))
    ->selectRaw('sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(`check_hours`))) as total_time')
    ->with('user')
    ->where('check_hours', '!=', null)
    ->when($this->selectDate && $this->selectDate2, function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('check_in', [$this->selectDate, Carbon::parse($this->selectDate2)->addDays(1)]);
    }, function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('check_in', [$this->selectDate, $this->selectDate2]);
    })
    ->groupBy('check_in', 'check_hours')
    ->get();
```

and I add `whereBetween` to make a range date to search

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rely to Laravel's [`QueryBuilder`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) instead of `Eloquent`. Given we are working with aggregates instead of mapping query result to objects.

```
DB::table('users')
  ->join('checks as c', 'users.id', '=', 'c.user_id')
  ->whereNotNull('c.check_hours')
  ->where(DB::raw('date(c.check_in)'), '2022-11-17')
  ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(c.check_in)'))
  ->select(
      DB::raw('date(c.check_in) as date'),
      DB::raw('group_concat(users.id) as user_ids'),
      DB::raw('sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(c.check_hours))) as total_time')
    )
  ->get();
```

Note: `DB::raw` is a powerful tool, though do avoid passing user-supplied parameter into it. In this case we use it only for calling mysql functions.

Comment: it gives errorr
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date(c.check_in)' in 'field list

Comment: @JuxhinTashi could you post the table structure in the question? tbh, i write the thing above based on your working query. so, i'm flying partly blind :)

Comment: i put the table of users and checks

Comment: @JuxhinTashi my bad, i should realized from the error that laravel consider `'date(c.check_in)'` as a column instead of calling sql function `date` on `c.check_in`. fyi, you can check the generated query by replacing the `->get()` with `->toSql()`.

Comment: `^ "select `date(c`.`check_in)` as `date`, `group_concat(users`.`id)` as `user_ids`, `sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(c`.`check_hours)))` as `total_time` from `users` inner join `checks` as `c` on `users`.`id` = `c`.`user_id` where `c`.`check_hours` is not null and `date(c`.`check_in)` = ? group by `date(c`.`check_in)``
it returns this but no results

Comment: @JuxhinTashi i just noticed, i wrote the date as `2022-11-14` different from yours that should be 17, may be thats the problem?

Comment: i fixed it by changing the query from` Users::query` to `Checks::query` so i could do the `selectRaw()` method and i got the results

Comment: @JuxhinTashi well, you could put it in as answer.